# Closed network system that use OSI model to connect to another network?

Tags: computer-networks

> The OSI model can be used for LAN and WAN networks, allowing the interconnection of [vendor] closed systems and it only informs what each layer have to do.

Someone said that this phrase is false, because OSI (Open Systems Interconnection) model, "as the name says", only allows the connection of "open systems".

So I'm wondering if there is any vendor closed network that, nonetheless, can communicate with another network using as the middle man an OSI based network. As I see it, in the broad sense of the phrase, two closed systems don't need to be directly connected to be interconnected, they can use a middle man.

Searching I only found about closed systems in the sense that they can't be freely joined.

Is that phrase true or false?

Comment: Where does the statement come from? And what is your actual question? In any case, this seems more of a legal or regulation than a computer science issue to me.

Comment: It's the interconnection model that's open, not necessarily the systems themselves.

Comment: OSI is a model, not a protocol. You communicate with protocols, not models. Models show how protocols work/can be analysed/though of.